# Standalone form of month name in Java date format

Tags: java, date-formatting

I need to format incomplete date only to month precision. My first guess was to apply pattern "MMMM yyyy" to it. This works fine for many locales (English, German, ...), but gives ugly result for languages with flexion, e.g. Russian. I read [documentation of `SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and found that 'L' is supposed to give context-insensitive month name: just what I need, as there is no day of month in the pattern. So I tried pattern "LLLL yyyy" instead. It works perfectly for Russian and other flexion languages, but instead fails for e.g. English and German...

Here is the test code:

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class test
{
    public static void main (String[] arguments) throws Exception
    {
        for (String locale : new String[] { "en", "de", "hu", "it", "ru", "fi", "pl" })
            System.out.format ("%s: %s \t%s\n", locale,
                               new SimpleDateFormat ("MMMM yyyy", new Locale (locale)).format (new Date ()),
                               new SimpleDateFormat ("LLLL yyyy", new Locale (locale)).format (new Date ()));
    }
}
```

And its output:

```
en: September 2015      0009 2015
de: September 2015      0009 2015
hu: szeptember 2015     szeptember 2015
it: settembre 2015      Settembre 2015
ru: сентября 2015       Сентябрь 2015
fi: syyskuuta 2015      syyskuu 2015
pl: września 2015       wrzesień 2015
```

So, for the tested locales: 'en' and 'de' work properly only with 'M', 'hu' is fine with both 'M' and 'L', 'it' is probably better off with 'L' (don't know how important capital letter is here), while 'ru', 'fi' and 'pl' give correct output only with 'L' (this I can really tell only for Russian and Polish, but I presume it's similar in Finnish).

Questions:

- Can I do something to make `SimpleDateFormat` or a similar date formatting class treat 'L' properly for all locales?
- Alternatively, is there a simple way to tell if 'M' or 'L' should be used for any given locale?

Comment: I don't speak russian but are you saying that `M` identifier gives an incorrect month name? What's the difference in meaning between 'сентября' and 'Сентябрь'?

Comment: Same as in Finnish. The month's name is syyskuu. But if there is a day mentioned it has to be: 15. syyskuuta (that is the meaning of standalone form vs. context sensitive).

Comment: Which version of Java 8 are you using? The `L` was introduced only in Java 8, and on my machine your program produces "September" for `en` and `de` as well. Perhaps you have a version with outdated locale files?

Comment: @RealSkeptic: That sounds plausible.  1.8.0_40 here.

Comment: I'm with JDK 1.8.0_51 and I have the same result as the OP

Comment: Mine is 1.8.0_60, tested on both Mac and Linux.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: Aha, thank you.  I'll see if upgrading our production machines is feasible.

Comment: JDK bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8114833 (it is for DateTimeFormatter but I guess it's the same for SimpleDateFormat)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an official bug - [JDK-8075548](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8075548)

The bug is in status "resolved", and you can see that the fix has been backported to versions 8_60 and 8_65, but not earlier versions of Java 8.

Therefore, the proper solution, if possible, is to upgrade to Java 1.8.0_60.

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

The `SimpleDateFormat` class is part of the troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

In java.time, the formatting pattern codes are similar to the old ones but next exactly the same. Be sure to study class doc for [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

```
final DateTimeFormatter fCombo = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "MMMM uuuu" );
final DateTimeFormatter fStandalone = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "LLLL uuuu" );

final LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now ( ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" ) );
for ( final String locale : new String[] { "en" ,  "fr" , "de" , "hu" , "it" , "ru" , "fi" , "pl" } ) {
    final Locale l = new Locale ( locale );

    System.out.format (
            "%s: %s | %s\n",
            locale,
            localDate.format ( fCombo.withLocale ( l ) ),
            localDate.format ( fStandalone.withLocale ( l ) )
    );
}
```

> en: March 2017 | 3 2017
>
> fr: mars 2017 | 3 2017
>
> de: März 2017 | 3 2017
>
> hu: március 2017 | március 2017
>
> it: marzo 2017 | Marzo 2017
>
> ru: марта 2017 | Март 2017
>
> fi: maaliskuuta 2017 | maaliskuu 2017
>
> pl: marca 2017 | marzec 2017

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).